# How can I export prefab or an object in Unity runtime as FBX files? I want to select objects and export as FBX in runtime. I need the way(script)

Tags: unity-game-engine, export, runtime, fbx, prefab

I want to export some objects that I selected in playing in Unity, so I want to write the script for that but it's too difficult for me.
Of course I can Export objects with FBX Exporter not playing but I just want to select objects and export them in runtime.
Can I get some scripts for that? I've searched so many times but I wasn't able to find it...